# No valid operation is selected by Dropbox connector in mule

Tags: mule, dropbox, dropbox-api, mule-studio, mule-component

I try to create a simple application using Mule. Anyway when I select operation "Authorize" I got error. But if I select another operation it works fine!!
[image]

I have Mule Server version="CE-3.8.1" and use Anypoint studio Version: 6.2.5

The Complete XML Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:dropbox="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dropbox" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dropbox http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/dropbox/current/mule-dropbox.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration8881" host="localhost" port="8881" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <dropbox:config name="Dropbox1" appKey="ovy1i8ak8u43t87" appSecret="7jlhpdzeyddi8d5" doc:name="Dropbox">
        <dropbox:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8881" remotePort="8881" path="callback"/>
    </dropbox:config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="www.mulesoft.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="dropbox_integration2Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration8881" path="/authorize" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dropbox:unauthorize config-ref="Dropbox1" doc:name="Dropbox - authorize"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="dropbox_integration2Flow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration8881" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dropbox:create-folder config-ref="Dropbox1" path="/mule" doc:name="Dropbox - create"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/sites/default/files/3C_mulesoft_logo_updated.svg" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dropbox:upload-stream config-ref="Dropbox1" filename="mulelogo.png" path="/mule" doc:name="Dropbox - upload"/>
        <dropbox:get-link config-ref="Dropbox1" path="/mule/mulelogo.png" doc:name="Dropbox - get link"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Is there any reason for this? How to fix it?

Comment: can you try restarting APS?

Comment: @RamakrishnaN I did but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the old **Mule Dropbox Cloud Connector Mule Studio Extension 3.3.0** (2013). Are you using that one? If you are, I suggest you use the latest available version, **Dropbox Connector 3.3.3** (2015), which fixes the error.

Comment: I am using latest Dropbox Connector Version: 3.3.3 (Runtime Version : 3.5)

Comment: That's odd. I can only reproduce it in 3.3.0. Can you share the XML of your app?